# In btsync/BitTorrent Sync, how can I add multiple folders and secrets to the sync.conf file?

Tags: sync, bittorrent

In sync.conf, it appears that only the first set of "secret" and "dir" values is available for remote syncs, although "secret" values that appear subsequently in the JSON file aren't seen by the remote clients as invalid.

I've tried entering

```
"shared_folders": [{"secret": "secret1", "dir": "/dirpath1"},{"secret": "secret2", "dir": "/dirpath2"}]
```

as the notation, as well as

```
"shared_folders": [{"secret": "secret1", "dir": "/dirpath1","secret": "secret2", "dir": "/dirpath2"}]
```

But the first example results in only the first share being synced, while the second example seems to result in no shares being synced. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second example is an obvious fail (you encapsulate different folders with `{}`). For the first, maybe there is an unsynced file `(.!sync)` somewhere?

Try syncing a third folder and see if that works. Then copy the files over to that one.